# jQuery fallback for scale3d?

Tags: jquery, css

So, I've been using CSS3's scale3d effect, which has been great. But, it won't work for IE9 and lower. I've tried using jQuery UI's 'scale', but it's crap.

Does anyone know of a jQuery equivalent or a plug-in to replace scale3d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 and lower don't support 3D transforms, so **no.**

The best you can get is `-ms-transform: scale(2)` in IE9 and some [transform matrix in IE8-](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/), like:

```
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
            M11=2,
            M12=0,
            M21=0,
            M22=2,
            SizingMethod='auto expand');
```